# Bedeutung von »es sei gesagt«

Tags: meaning

Im folgenden Beispiel:

> Interesse der Bauern und der Verbraucher brauchen wir klare und transparente Vorgaben auch für die
>    [...] Tierernährung, ***aber es sei gesagt***, dass die Bauern immer [...] die ersten Geschädigten sind, wenn es hier zu Missständen kommt.

Was bedeutet »es sei gesagt«?

Comment: "*vielleicht wussten Sie es nicht*"

Comment: Eigentlich bedeutet es gar nichts - es ist eine ziemlich leere Worthülse, denn alleine die Tatsache, dass etwas gesagt wird, sagt ja schon dasselbe aus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Es sei gesagt, dass ...

bedeutet

> Es ist notwendig, dass gesagt wird, dass ...

Damit drückt man aus, dass das, was nach *»dass«* folgt, etwas ist, das wichtig ist. Es ist etwas, das jeder erfahren muss. Es ist also etwas, das unbedingt gesagt werden muss.

Comment: Und ist das ein umgangssprachlicher Ausdruck?

Comment: Interessant. Tofro hat in seinem Kommentar zur Frage geschrieben, dass es eine leere Worthülse sei, die nichts bedeutet. Hier gibt es aber zwei Antworte die den gegensatz sagen.

Comment: Politiker pflegen sowas zu sagen wie: "Ich sage: die Steuern müssen erhöht werden!" - Und ich denke: Ich hör's doch - warum muß er mir extra sagen, dass er's sagt?

Comment: @Dreikäsehoch: Das ist Standarddeutsch, und wird so z.B. auch in offiziellen Dokumenten der EU und diverser anderer Organisationen verwendet: http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/es+sei+gesagt.html (Beachte die Quellenangaben der Zitate)

Comment: @tofro: Dreikäsehoch hat aber nicht gefragt, was *»ich sage«* bedeutet (das ist tatsächlich eine leere Worthülse). Er hat gefragt, was *»es sei gesagt«* bedeutet. Das bedeutet nämlich eben nicht »ich sage«, sondern: »Es ist wichtig, dass es jemand sagt« (Hervorheben der Wichtigkeit)

Comment: Eigentlich nicht.  Es ist nur ein "Imperativ an sich selbst" und hört sich damit für mich nur noch dümmer an. Aber das ist möglicherweise nur meine persönliche Ansicht - Genauso, wie wenn Leute sagen "Ich würde meinen..." (meinst du nun, oder meinst du nicht?)

Answer (score 2):

Dieses *»aber es sei gesagt«* ist eine Betonung des Autors, dessen Bedeutung man auch mit

> aber ich will an dieser Stelle ausdrücklich erwähnen

formulieren könnte.